# how to do this query in oracle is there something missing

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle12c

```
SELECT   ( select (NVL((SELECT AMOUNT  
    FROM ASGN_TRNS_TBL 
    WHERE 
        TRNS_DATE = '1-SEP-18' --v_current_date 
        AND DEP_ID = 1--v_current_department 
        AND ACC_NO =6),0)

        +

    -- 5 account
    NVL((SELECT AMOUNT 
    FROM ASGN_TRNS_TBL 
    WHERE 
        TRNS_DATE = '1-SEP-18'--v_current_date 
        AND DEP_ID = 1--v_current_department 
        AND ACC_NO = 5),0)) FROM DUAL  

        /

    -- 2 account
SELECT (NVL((SELECT AMOUNT 
    FROM ASGN_TRNS_TBL 
    WHERE 
        TRNS_DATE  ='1-SEP-18'-- v_current_date 
        AND DEP_ID = 1--v_current_department 
        AND ACC_NO = 2),0)

        +

    -- 3 account
    NVL((SELECT AMOUNT 
    FROM ASGN_TRNS_TBL 
    WHERE 
        TRNS_DATE  = '1-SEP-18'--v_current_date 
        AND DEP_ID = 1--v_current_department 
        AND ACC_NO = 3),0)) FROM DUAL )

        FROM DUAL;
```

my question is how to get values from this query. I want to do is something like this (select amount + select amount)/(select other amount+ select another amount) and get the total value using FROM DUAL key word...

Comment: `'1-SEP-18'` is not a `DATE` value, it is a string!

Comment: no but when i execute code piece  by  piece it works .. I want to get the full answer

Comment: assuming the "date" column isn't a varchar column, then you should be using `to_date()` something like this `where trans_date = to_date('2018-09-01','yyyy-mm-dd')` and not relying on language dependent strings

Comment: @Used_By_Already: Or simply use a Standard SQL *date literal* which is supported by Oracle for years:  `date '2018-09-01'`

Comment: You should definitely try to adapt @D-Shih's solution, it's short, fast and readable. In your query you are missing one closing and one opening bracket (before and after `/`, just replace it with ` ) / (` ), [here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/394b0/2) is working demo. Use `sum`s if there are more rows for each `acc_no`.

Answer (score 0):

You can try to use *condition aggregate function*  instead of subquery in `select`

```
SELECT SUM(CASE WHEN TRNS_DATE = TO_DATE('01-09-2018' ,'DD-MM-YYYY') AND DEP_ID = 1 AND ACC_NO IN (5,6) THEN AMOUNT ELSE 0 END) /
       SUM(CASE WHEN TRNS_DATE = TO_DATE('01-09-2018' ,'DD-MM-YYYY') AND DEP_ID = 1 AND ACC_NO IN (2,3) THEN AMOUNT ELSE 0 END) 
FROM ASGN_TRNS_TBL
```

**NOTE**

`TRNS_DATE` seem like date type value. you need to use `TO_DATE` function 
convert `'1-SEP-18'` to date type otherwise, it will be a string.

Comment: is it not possible to use sub queries like i have used.. coz i want to use it like that for this case other wise you method cannot be integrated i think

Comment: everything works perfect when execute sub-queries one by one.. there is a typo I think ..But i cant point what is it coz i'm new to oracle pl/sql

Comment: I think the problem is on `'1-SEP-18'` you need to use `TO_DATE ` let the string to `date` datatype